# Generating @1x, @2x, @3x, @4x sprites with Sass

Tags: compass-sass, sprite-sheet, retina, hdpi

I'm wanting to create retina sprites to support @1x, @2x, @3x, @4x retina displays.  I'm using Codekit, hooked up to an external version of Compass.  I've tried a few plugins out:
https://github.com/AdamBrodzinski/Retina-Sprites-for-Compass

https://github.com/Gaya/Retina-Sprites-for-Compass

which allow for the easy creation of @1x and @2x, but I can't find a simple solution for creating the other sizes.
I'd like to be able to include the sprite on any class or pseudo class rather than generating a separate sprites stylesheet or block of CSS.

In an ideal world, all the sprites would be on one spritesheet as I don't think I'll be using any javascript to preload and I'd like to have as few HTTPs requests as possible

Thank you for your time,